# sas9 command to add 1 year to an existing date

Tags: date, sas

I  have a dataset which contains a column YEARENDDATE. If I want to change all the rows below it e.g.

```
from 31DEC2010 to 31DEC2011
from 31DEC2011 to 31DEC2012
from 31DEC2012 to 31DEC2013
from 31DEC2013 to 31DEC2014
from 31OCT2010 to 31OCT2011
```

and so on.

What is the SAS command in version 9 that I can use to change the existing column?

Thanks and hope to hear from you soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **INTNX** function:

```
INTNX(custom-interval, start-from, increment <, 'alignment'>)
```

In your case, it can be

```
YEARENDDATE1 = intnx("year",YEARENDDATE,1,'same');
```

There is new variable called YEARENDDATE1, you can compare now YEARENDDATE and YEARENDDATE1. Once you statisfied drop the YEARENDDATE and rename YEARENDDATE1 to YEARENDDATE.

I have created YEARENDDATE1 just to be on safer side, but you can override if you wish to( but i would not recommend it)

More on INTNX: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000212700.htm